# Getting the sum of the first 50 odd numbers not multiple of 5?

Tags: c, for-loop, sum

1- I got how to find the numbers, I just don't know how to link that to a sum for loop

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
int main () { 
int count, sum=0, i; 
     for (count=1;count<125;count=count+2)
             if(count%5 != 0) 
                     { //non multiple of 5
                     printf ("%d \t ",count);
                     }
         
                     for (i = 0; i<=count; i++) 
                     sum = sum + count;
                     printf("Sum= %d \t" , sum);   
return(0);   
}
```

Comment: Whats the inner loop doing? Just do `sum += count` __once__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67853645/getting-the-sum-of-the-first-50-odd-numbers-not-multiple-of-5/67853718#67853718) answer with one error corrected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1, hits = 0; hits < 50; i += 2)
    {
        if (i % 5)
        {
            printf("%d \t%c", i, !(hits % 10) ? '\n' : ' ');
            sum += i;
            ++hits;
        }
    }
    printf("\nGot sum %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rW9bMzhPc

Answer (score 1):

A single loop seems to suffice, here's a solution I threw together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1, hits = 0; hits < 50; i += 2)
    {
        if (i % 5 != 0)
        {
            sum += i;
            ++hits;
        }
    }
    printf("Got sum %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is 3124.